# Implementing Gasless Meta-Transactions for ERC20 Token's Approve Function: Is it Possible with Deployed Contracts like USDC or USDT?

Tags: erc-20, meta-transactions, gasless, erc2771

I am currently exploring the implementation of gasless transactions, specifically focusing on meta-transactions, to enhance user experience by subsidizing the gas fees. For this functionality to work seamlessly, I understand that the smart contract needs to be compliant with [ERC2771](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/metatx) standards.

My specific query revolves around established and already deployed ERC20 tokens, such as USDC and USDT. I am interested in making the 'approve' function transactions of these tokens gasless. However, I am uncertain whether this is feasible given that these contracts are already deployed and may not adhere to the ERC2771 standard.

Is there any workaround or method that would allow me to implement meta-transactions for the 'approve' function of these existing ERC20 tokens? Any guidance or insights on this matter would be highly appreciated, as it would greatly contribute to my project’s progression and user experience.

Comment: Apparently https://app.hashflow.com/ supports trading e.g. USDC to USDT, but I haven't dived into their code to validate it...